# Defining exceptions with tuple as argument

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to define an exception in OCaml that accepts a tuple pair of lists as an argument. However, this situation doesn't work?

```
# exception Foo of string list * string list;; 
exception Foo of string list * string list
# let bar = (["a"], ["b"; "c"; "d"]);;
val bar : string list * string list = (["a"], ["b"; "c"; "d"])
# raise(Foo bar);;
Error: The constructor Foo expects 2 argument(s),
       but is applied here to 1 argument(s)
```

However, if I do this, it works

```
# raise (Foo (["a"], ["b"; "c"; "d"]));;
Exception: Foo (["a"], ["b"; "c"; "d"]).
```

What's the deal? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking at this wrong (though I won't blame you: it's pretty surprising at first). It may seem to you that constructors follow the syntax `Name of type` where the type part follows normal type syntax (which lets it contain tuples).

In reality, tuples and constructors follow the exact same syntax: a constructor is merely a tuple with a name in front of it:

```
tuple/constructor == [name of] type [* type] [* type] ...
```

So, the `*` in a constructor definition are not part of the tuple syntax, they're part of the constructor syntax. You're literally defining a constructor as being **this name, followed by N arguments** as opposed to **this name, followed by an argument which is a tuple**.

The reason behind this subtle difference in behavior is one of performance. Right now, tuples and constructors are represented in memory as such:

```
[TYPE] [POINTER] [POINTER] [POINTER]
```

This is a fairly compact and efficient representation. If the multiple arguments of a constructor could indeed be accessed as a tuple, this would require the runtime to represent that tuple independently from the constructor (in order for it to be independently addressable) and so it would look like this:

```
[TYPE] [POINTER]
           |
           v
          [TYPE] [POINTER] [POINTER] [POINTER]
```

This would use marginally more memory, require twice as many allocations when using a constructor, and reduce the performance of pattern-matching tuples (because of an additional dereference). In order to retain maximum performance, the `name of type * type` is represented using the first pattern, and you need to explicitly type `name of (type * type)` to cut off the `*` from the `of` and thus fall back on the second pattern.

Note that both patterns are accessed through the same pattern-matching and construction syntax: `name (arg,arg)`. This means that type inference cannot deduce the pattern based on usage. This is no problem for normal constructors, which are always defined in a type definition, but it causes variants (which need no preliminary definition) to automatically fall back on the *second* version.

Additional reading on the memory representation of types [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual032.html#toc138).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the lengthy explanation! Your understanding of OCaml makes it seem like you are from INRIA

Answer (score 5):

In this respect, OCaml's exception constructors are just like ordinary constructors:

`Constr(1,2,3)` is a special syntactic construct in which no triple occurs. On the other hand, a triple occurs in `Constr((1,2,3))`. The implementation matches this behavior, with `Constr(1,2,3)` being allocated as a single block, and `Constr((1,2,3))` as two blocks, one containing a pointer to the other(the triple). In the run-time representation of `Constr(1,2,3)` there is no triple to get a pointer to, and if you need one you have to allocate a fresh one.

Note: `Constr(((1,2,3)))` is equivalent to `Constr((1,2,3))`. In `Constr(((1,2,3)))`, the middle parentheses are interpreted as going around the expression `(1,2,3)`, and parentheses around an expression are forgotten in the abstract syntax tree.

Answer (score 4):

`Foo` is a constructor of an exception with 2 parameters.  You'd have to decompose the tuple and pass each part into it.

```
# exception Foo of string list * string list;;
exception Foo of string list * string list
# let bar = (["a"], ["b"; "c"; "d"]);;
val bar : string list * string list = (["a"], ["b"; "c"; "d"])
# let a, b = bar in raise (Foo (a, b));;
Exception: Foo (["a"], ["b"; "c"; "d"]).
```

If you wish to use a tuple as the single parameter, you must define the exception using parens and pass the tuple in.

```
# exception Foo of (string list * string list);;
exception Foo of (string list * string list)
# let bar = (["a"], ["b"; "c"; "d"]);;
val bar : string list * string list = (["a"], ["b"; "c"; "d"])
# raise (Foo bar);;
Exception: Foo (["a"], ["b"; "c"; "d"]).
```